# Need help on like/dislike voting system

Tags: algorithm, system, social-media-like

I'd like to get some help to build a like/dislike sorting algorithm to find the best entries. I thought about a way to do it, but there are two major flaws with this method and I'd like to know if there's any better way.

Here's how I thought about doing it:

The entries would be sorted by the ratio given by `l/d` where `l = number of likes` and `d = number of dislikes`, so that those with a higher ratio have a bigger likes count and deserve a higher up place than those with a low ratio.

There are two issues with this method:

**1:** if the number of dislikes is 0 the `l/d` will be impossible. So even if an entry has a thousand of likes and 0 dislikes it still won't get any place into the scoreboard.

**2:** entries with a low amount of likes and dislikes are at an advantage in comparison with those with many ratings since it takes a low amount of ratings to influence the ratio and give the entry a good score.

What do you think?

**EDIT**: Here's a possible alternative that fixes the 1st issue: `(l + 1) / (d + 1)`. Any feedback on this one?

Comment: +1 because I'm sure this is a very common problem with a strong mathematical/statistical answer but I don't know the best solution off the top of my head.

Comment: Here's some interesting information on how Reddit does it: http://amix.dk/blog/post/19588

Comment: @FogleBird [the XKCD version](http://blog.reddit.com/2009/10/reddits-new-comment-sorting-system.html)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This might be relevant: [How Not To Sort By Average Rating](http://www.evanmiller.org/how-not-to-sort-by-average-rating.html).

Answer (score 2):

To remove the division by zero, you might add 1 to the numerator and denominator to obtain (l+1)/(d+1).  If you want to more highly rank entries with more likes, then you might multiply your ranking formula by log(number of likes + 1). Here the one is added to remove the mathematical error that results if the entry has zero likes.  For the discussion that follows, assume that the log has a base of 10.  So a ranking formula that meets the requirements would be (likes + 1)/(dislikes + 1) * log(likes + 1).

Observe that this formula provides a rank of 0 if there are no likes because log(1) = 0.  Suppose that the votes are tied with one like vote and one dislike vote.  Then the rank is 2/2*log(2) = 0.3 because log(2) = 0.3.  Now consider another tie with 9 likes and 9 dislikes.  Then the rank is 10/10*log(10) = 1, because log(10) = 1.  That is, the log(likes) term ranks ties with more likes more highly than ties with fewer likes.

Comment: After writing this, I noticed your edit that provided the (l+1)/(d+1) fix.

Comment: Nice, the only problem being that intuitively you'd want something with 0 likes and 0 dislikes score higher than 0 likes and 1000 dislikes.

Answer (score 0):

This has worked the best for me.

`rank = likes * 100 / (likes + dislikes)`

It orders by higher likes, then any like and/or dislike activity, then no activity.
examples:

```
likes, dislikes => rank
0, 0 => 0            //avoid /0 error
3, 3 => 50
3, 0 => 100
```